# LINQ: Multi table/ join + Group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a rather unusual set of tables which I need to write a Linq query for and return a specific custom model, the following are the entities , and their relationships

```
    public class CustomerAccount
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
        public Guid ShopId { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        public string MyAreaName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerAccountTag> CustomerAccountTags { get; set; }

    }

    public class Shop
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerAccountTag
    {
        public Guid CustomerAccountId { get; set; }
        public string TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerAccount CustomerAccount { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerAccountTag> CustomerAccountTags { get; set; }
    }
```

CustomerAccount holds list of customers as well as their shop and their account details, plus some meta data.

It would contains records like below

```
{
  "CustomerAccount": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "ShopId": "Shop1",
      "AccountId": "AccountA"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "ShopId": "Shop1",
      "AccountId": "AccountB"
    },
    {
      "Id": "3",
      "ShopId": "Shop2",
      "AccountId": "AccountC"
    }
  ]
}
```

The table CustomerAccountTag is just a linking table between CustomerAccount and Tags table, tags are strings assigned to each CustomerAccount row.

I need the following output,
Group by shop Id (so the above example would have two rows of data one for shop1 and another one for shop2)
Each row will have the following as the data

```
{
  ShopName
  ShopId
  Accounts = "custom list of accounts per shop, with Account Id, Account Name, AreaName and a list of related Tags"
}
```

The following is how I have done it and it works but only with LINQ lambda, the issue is I can't "group by" unless I return the joined tables as list then I can work on it. Otherwise it complains that it can't run the query on the server and it needs to be evaluated on the client!

```
        var queryResults = (from e in _applicationDbContext.CustomerAccount
                           .Include(g => g.Shop)
                           .Include(y => y.Account)
                           .Include(a => a.CustomerAccountTag)
                           .ThenInclude(t => t.Tag)
                           select e).ToList();

            var result = queryResults.GroupBy(x => x.Shop)
                         .Select(y => new CustomAccountResponse
                         {
                             ShopId = y.Key.Id,
                             ShopName = y.Key.Name,
                             Accounts = y.Select(x => new { y.Account.Name, y.Account.Id, y.AreaName, string.Join(",", y.CustomerAccountTags.Select(x => x.Tag.Name)) })
                         });
```

Was wondering if I can do the same thing with Linq but run everything on the database rather than half there and half on the client!

**UPDATED:**

I think the following sample code will explain the issue, perhaps EFCore doesn't support what I am asking for

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var shop1 = new Shop { Name = "Shop1" };
                var shop2 = new Shop { Name = "Shop2" };
                var shop3 = new Shop { Name = "Shop3" };
                var shop4 = new Shop { Name = "Shop4" };
                var shop5 = new Shop { Name = "Shop3" };

                List<Shop> shop = new List<Shop>() { shop1, shop2, shop3, shop4, shop5 };

                context.Shops.AddRange(shop);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {

                var query = from shop in context.Shops
                            group shop by shop.Name into grouped
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = grouped.Key,
                                Count = grouped.Count(),
                                Items = grouped
                            };
            }

            /*
            Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
            KeySelector: s.Name, 
            ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
            EntityType: Shop
            ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False
            ' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in Entity Framework. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
            */
            
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    public class Shop
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Can I actually get list of the grouped items in my query?
That's exactly where the following exception happens

```
            /*
            Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
            KeySelector: s.Name, 
            ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
            EntityType: Shop
            ValueBufferExpression: 
            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
            IsNullable: False
            ' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in Entity Framework. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
            */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created correct query. There is no easy way to run this query completely on the server using EF. What you can do here - limit data retrieved from the server and force EF to generate optimal query.

```cs
var query = 
   from a in _applicationDbContext.CustomerAccount
   from t in a.CustomerAccountTags
   select new 
   {
      Shop = new { a.Shop.Id, a.Shop.Name },
      Account = new { a.Account.Name, a.Account.Id, a.AreaName },
      TagName = t.Tag.Name
   };

var result = 
   from q in query.AsEnumerable()
   group q by q.Shop into g
   select new CustomAccountResponse
   {
       ShopId = g.Key.Id,
       ShopName = g.Key.Name,
       Accounts = g.GroupBy(x => x.Account).Select(x => new 
          { 
             x.Key.Account.Name, 
             x.Key.Account.Id, 
             x.Key.Account.AreaName, 
             Tags = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.TagName))
          }).ToList()
   };
```

Comment: Thanks very much, yes, your method works.  Perhaps I am confused about what EFCore supports, I have updated my post with a sample code, would you kindly look to see if that explains the issue?

Comment: You can not do that. Items are not available for selecting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377955/linq-to-database-how-to-group-entities-properly-and-groupby-limitations